# What preparations are needed for putting a scientific explorer base on another planet?

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, earth-like

In my book, a group of scientific explorers want to put a base on the planet so what would I need to make that possible? The planet is a super-Earth but has lower gravity than Earth. The ship they use to enter the atmosphere is small. It can hold 6 people and the driver.

The goal isn't to live in a home-like building but to have a base of operations so they can live, explore and make scientific discoveries.

What is the best way to send resources without minimizing shuttle trips from surface to orbit?.

Comment: There is a good question here but I have become spoiled by reading spellchecked documents.  Hitting "cuase" is like finding a hair in the guacamole.  Erik there is a built in spellchecker on the WB stack!  Edit this document, take the suggestions of the spellchecker, capitalize the start of sentences - all that stuff they taught you to do when writing communications intended for people other than yourself.--- hm I see Nycto took care of it.   Give a man a fish, Nycto...

Comment: How advanced is robotics in your universe? In classic Sci-Fi, explorers just land on a planet, and all kinds of things would unwind from there. In a more realistic future world, robots/drones would do a lot of preparations before first human arrives.

Comment: the robots would do preperations first such as scaning planets temp,atmosphere see if it has breatable air and are build for certian task.they can also be send to planets but just like real life its expensive and worthless if it crashes when it lands or goes offline so a little more advanced but it still has problems

Comment: @ErikSanchez worth remembering that remote-controlling stuff from orbit will be quite straightforward and responsive... remember that humans already remote control things in space from arbitrary places on the ground so the technology is already there. In the future when we've solved the problem of interstellar travel, remote controlling nearby drones like this would be child's play.

Comment: Last sentence: " without using the ship to go back to the shuttle and back down to the planet"  Should probably be: minimizing shuttle trips from surface to orbit?.

Comment: i should probely make those obtinal i just wanted to list the things i thought people would ask about like try this or that

Comment: Any question with infinite answers will probably get closed. Give us a box of options or make a go/no-go test. “Preparations” can be anything from designing landing pads to raising funds or getting daycare arrangements for the kids. What planet do you want to land on? What supplies do you need.? If you don’t know, those become separate questions.

Comment: @Erik Sanchez This sounds like classic Sci-Fi - very limited automated exploration, no site preparation.

Comment: This is in the VTR queue, but I cannot give it my vote. The question is vague. Worse, it's looking for "best," which is subjective and story-based (best compared to what?). To be reopened, please [edit] your question and (a) make the title Q and the body Q identical, (b) explain in detail what resources are being moved, (c) explain in detail the conditions on the planet where they're landing, (d) be sure to ask one and only one Q (you can only ask one, inviting us to only answer one is forbidden).

Comment: How long will they be there? What conditions on the planet? Can they count on sunlight to grow food? Is there severe weather to worry about? High winds, temperature ranges, flood, drought, snow, etc.? Is there indiginous biology to worry about? Prepping for Mars is totally different to prepping for Venus.

Comment: "*What is the best way to send resources without minimizing shuttle trips  from surface to orbit?*" Huh? Isn't the obvious answer to use shuttles to transport everything?

Comment: Dan the planet is a super earth (if that changes things let me know) and has a higher oxygen percentage like the carboniferus and cambrian.they use sun to grow earth plants and alien plants that are found on the planet.they are in a dessert that is in a drought and the planet has frequent rainstorms and some high winds the cost of the super continet are normaly eroded cuase of excessive floodin.and the planet has snow as well as alien animals.

Comment: also dan they will be there as long as they need but for now lets say 6 earth months.also DKNguyen the shuttles are meant for entering the ships small shuttles dont have enough fuel or power to leave the planet but that will be solved later in the story.

Answer (score 2):

**Apollo style!**

[image: apollo wth chutes]

http://www.earthtothemoon.com/ap_17_parachute.html

Just drop dumb drops.  They don't even need to be drones.  That worked for Apollo.  Your re-entry drop vehicles will need heat shields because they will need to shed orbital velocity and they will need parachutes to fall nice and slow.  Probably a locator beacon.  Wait for nice weather.

You could drop a bunch of these ahead of time too, unless you are worried the natives will get to them first.  Maybe put locks on the capsules.  If the locals want to make swanky togas out of the striped parachutes that is ok.

Comment: funny enough i have thought of this it was in the back of my head also there is no species that have gained human intelligence on this planet

Comment: Upgrade the chute for maneuvarability and give it the ability to try to home in on a radio beacon. This should keep most of your pre-dropped supplies closer together.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic information**

Before you send and land humans on the planet, you need to get basic information about the environment. If somebody is staying on that planet, he will need

- oxygen
- food
- water supply
- suitable temperature
- suitable atmospheric pressure
- safety from local creatures, insects, bacteria, gases, radiation etc.

**Probe**

You need to send some probe to investigate the environment. This probe will have sensors, cameras, communication system. It will send you the necessary information. Based on this information, you can decide in a better way what is already available on the planet and what you need to take with.